# output text in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with vscode in jupyter notebooks and when executing a code the text suddenly looks out of range, before it looked normal, I tried reinstalling vscode.

This is the view I have from the github repository, before it looked like this in vscode:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTshO.png)

in vscode suddenly it started to look like this:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgNxE.png)

before they told me that the font is the problem and that I should edit the json of the configuration, however, the json is only with the theme for vscode since I have uninstalled everything related and I have reinstalled it, and it still continues the same

Comment: What do you mean by "text suddenly looks out of range" ? Which text in the screenshot are you referring to?

Comment: sorry for my english, the text that should come out when executing the code, should be tabulated, that is, a column separated from the other in the same margin

Comment: Even if the output is not properly formatted in vscode, why use two different operations to show it? Show both outputs from the same operation, be it types or info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to VSCode, you can wait for the update of VSCode. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144350) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your font has changed from fixed width to variable width. This is something you will find in `settings.json` but should change via VSCode's settings page. Search for "font" and select an appropriate option - perhaps Courier.

Comment: I check the configurations and the json (which is empty, only with the name of the theme that is dark), the configurations for the font are as you indicate [Font Family: Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace].
and still the same, I think it happened when I changed the theme of vscode, but after reinstalling and deleting all the configurations it should have returned to its previous state